# Como trazer vendedores que fizeram e não fizeram vendas no dia de ontem?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Neste select estou trazendo todos os funcionários que acessaram o aplicativo ontem `PO.DAT_COLETA` e que realizaram vendam ontem `PE.COD_PEDIDO`. Mas eu também quero trazer os que acessaram ontem e não fizeram vendas, hoje faço isso por PROCV no excel, é possível fazer isso pela query ?

```
 SELECT

     FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
    ,UV.NOM_UNIDADE_VENDA
    ,FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO
    ,FU.NOM_FUNCIONARIO
    ,PO.DAT_COLETA
    ,PE.COD_PEDIDO

    FROM FUNCIONARIO_UNIDADE_VENDA FUV

    JOIN POSICAO_FUNCIONARIO PO ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO
    JOIN UNIDADE_VENDA UV ON FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA = UV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
    JOIN FUNCIONARIO FU ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = FU.COD_FUNCIONARIO
    JOIN PEDIDO PE ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PE.COD_FUNCIONARIO

    WHERE 
    PO.DAT_COLETA >= CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101) and PO.DAT_COLETA < CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 
AND PE.DAT_ENTREGA >= CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101) and PE.DAT_ENTREGA < CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 

    ORDER BY FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
```

Comment: Uma duvida, pq vc converte sua data para char e depois compara com outra data?

Comment: Estou apenas testando, depois isso vai ser retirado. Na verdade esta query vai ter que ser rodada 23:59, para trazer todas as pessoas que acessaram e fizeram ou não fizeram vendas no dia. É um relatório retroativo, entende? Pois se a pessoa acessar hoje a dat_coleta é sobreposta no banco e fura o relatório.

Comment: @LucasEduardodaSilva (1) Se o funcionário acessar o aplicativo várias vezes no mesmo dia, na tabela POSICAO_FUNCIONARIO há uma linha para cada acesso no dia ou somente uma e única linha no dia? // (2) 
A cada dia o funcionário registra um único pedido global de vendas ou pode registrar vários pedidos de venda para o mesmo dia?

Comment: @LucasEduardodaSilva (1) Como estão declaradas as colunas DAT_COLETA e DAT_ENTREGA? (date, datetime, string etc). // (2) Se for como string, qual o formato? (dd/mm/aaaa, mm/dd/aaaa etc)

Comment: @José Diz Sim, estão declaradas como datetime, e cada nova coleta que o aparelho envia ao banco ele sobrepõe a última, ou seja, existe apenas uma linha com a dat_coleta mais recente sempre, por isto esse script será agendado para rodar sempre 23:59, abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eis sugestão, considerando-se as informações disponíveis.

```
-- código #1 v3
-- obtém horários de limite do dia 
declare @Data1 datetime, @Data2 datetime;
set @Data1= Cast(Current_timestamp as date);
set @Data2= DateAdd(ms, -3, DateAdd(day, +1, @Data1));

--
SELECT FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA, UV.NOM_UNIDADE_VENDA,
       PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO, FU.NOM_FUNCIONARIO,
       case when exists (SELECT * from PEDIDO as PE 
                         where PE.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO
                               and PE.DAT_ENTREGA between @Data1 and @Data2)
            then 'Vendeu' 
            else 'Não vendeu' end as Status
  from POSICAO_FUNCIONARIO as PO
       inner join FUNCIONARIO_UNIDADE_VENDA as FUV on FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO
       inner join UNIDADE_VENDA as UV on FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA = UV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
       inner join FUNCIONARIO as FU on FU.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO
  where PO.DAT_COLETA between @Data1 and @Data2
  order by FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA asc, Status desc, PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO asc;
```

---

A sugestão assume que:

- vários pedidos podem ser registrados no mesmo dia, para um mesmo
  funcionário;
- as colunas DAT_COLETA e DAT_ENTREGA estão declaradas como datetime.

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão! tentarei amanhã no trabalho. Ainda preciso desenvolver uma variante deste script, o qual traz ambas as revendas que acessaram o aplicativo e realizaram e não realizaram vendas, sem trazer linhas duplicadas, pois eu consigo esta informação pela tabela funcionario_unidade_venda

Comment: @LucasEduardodaSilva Fiz modificações no código #1, considerando-se as informações adicionais que forneceu. E corrigi um erro, pois havia me esquecido do `end` no `case`. // Somente estou em dúvida com relação aos pedidos. Na tabela PEDIDO pode existir mais de um pedido para um mesmo funcionário, no mesmo dia?

Comment: Sim, podem existir vários registros na tabela PEDIDO para um mesmo funcionário, ele pode fazer várias vendas durante o dia. Agradecido!

Comment: @LucasEduardodaSilva: Ok. Então me parece que o código #1 está de acordo com o que solicitou, e sem trazer linhas repetidas. Aguardo retorno.

Comment: Sim, funcionou perfeitamente, não trouxe linhas repetidas, é uma variante que posso apresentar, muito obrigado pelo apoio ! Tenho pouco tempo de SQL. Grato !!

Answer (score 3):

Sim é possível, faça um UNION o primeiro você já tem que é os que fizeram venda, já o segundo faça quase mesma coisa, porém, sem tabela de pedidos.

```
/* FUNCIONARIOS QUE REALIZARAM VENDA */
SELECT
 FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
,UV.NOM_UNIDADE_VENDA
,FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO
,FU.NOM_FUNCIONARIO
,PO.DAT_COLETA
,PE.COD_PEDIDO
FROM FUNCIONARIO_UNIDADE_VENDA FUV
JOIN POSICAO_FUNCIONARIO PO ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO
JOIN UNIDADE_VENDA UV ON FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA = UV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
JOIN FUNCIONARIO FU ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = FU.COD_FUNCIONARIO
JOIN PEDIDO PE ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PE.COD_FUNCIONARIO
WHERE PO.DAT_COLETA >= CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101) and PO.DAT_COLETA    < CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 
AND PE.DAT_ENTREGA >= CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101) and PE.DAT_ENTREGA < CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 
UNION
/* FUNCIONARIOS QUE NÃO REALIZARAM VENDA */
SELECT
 FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
,UV.NOM_UNIDADE_VENDA
,FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO
,FU.NOM_FUNCIONARIO
,PO.DAT_COLETA
,0 AS COD_PEDIDO
  FROM FUNCIONARIO_UNIDADE_VENDA FUV
 JOIN POSICAO_FUNCIONARIO PO ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO
 JOIN UNIDADE_VENDA UV ON FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA = UV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
 JOIN FUNCIONARIO FU ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = FU.COD_FUNCIONARIO
 WHERE PO.DAT_COLETA >= CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101) and  PO.DAT_COLETA < CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 
 ORDER BY 1
```

Também é possível fazer utilizando LEFT JOIN com a tabela 'PEDIDO', sendo assim, caso não exista pedido, ficará null o campo do número do pedido.

Comment: Ruberlei Cardoso, acredito que eu não consiga usar um UNION pois nem todos os que acessaram ontem fizeram venda. Mas alguns que acessaram ontem, fizeram mais de uma venda! isso dá diferença no número de registros entre as duas querys impossibilitando o UNION.

Comment: Da para fazer sim, quando se utiliza o UNION não precisa ter a mesma quantidade de registros e sim a mesma quantidade de campos e que sejam do mesmo tipo.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito, resolveu o caso!

Comment: Notei que os vendedores que fizeram venda ele traz tudo certo, mas sempre trás uma linha com cod_pedido = 0 e depois traz as linhas com os pedidos efetivamente, é possível eliminar essa linha com o cod_pedido = 0 somente para os vendedores que tiveram vendas? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT

 FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
,UV.NOM_UNIDADE_VENDA
,FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO
,FU.NOM_FUNCIONARIO
,PO.DAT_COLETA
,PE.COD_PEDIDO

FROM FUNCIONARIO_UNIDADE_VENDA FUV

JOIN POSICAO_FUNCIONARIO PO ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PO.COD_FUNCIONARIO
JOIN UNIDADE_VENDA UV ON FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA = UV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
JOIN FUNCIONARIO FU ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = FU.COD_FUNCIONARIO
LEFT JOIN PEDIDO PE ON FUV.COD_FUNCIONARIO = PE.COD_FUNCIONARIO

WHERE 
PO.DAT_COLETA >= CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101) and PO.DAT_COLETA < CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AND PE.DAT_ENTREGA >= CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101) and PE.DAT_ENTREGA < CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) 
ORDER BY FUV.COD_UNIDADE_VENDA
```

Outra opção é utilizar o LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!